# the cycle says that all rows have the '|'

Tags: python, pandas, python-re, cycle

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a|b', 'b', 'c|r'], [ 'e', 'f', 'g']]), columns=['First', 'Second', 'Third'])

for elem in df_test.get('First'):
    x = bool(re.search('|', elem))
    if x == True:
        print(elem)
```

Output:

```
a|b
e
```

---

Why does it show like that? It's considered that only the first row must be in output. No?

Comment: Escape the `|`: `re.search(r"\|", elem)`

Comment: `|` has special meaning in a regex search. All entries have either and empty string or an empty string somewhere within the string.

Comment: Why would you use a regex anyway if you just want to match one character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is with the regular expression pattern and how it interacts with the `re.search` function. In regular expressions, the vertical bar `|` is a special character that represents an **OR** operator. So when you use `re.search('|', elem)`, it is essentially searching for an empty string or any character in the input elem.So, You need to escape the vertical bar using a backslash `\` because you want to match the literal character `|`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a|b', 'b', 'c|r'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]), columns=['First', 'Second', 'Third'])

for elem in df_test.get('First'):
    x = bool(re.search('\|', elem))
    if x == True:
        print(elem)
```